# load third party js scripts to jhipster webpack in custom path

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster

I have an xxx.js script file with a 3mb value.
As described in Jhipster README Ive been imported in vendor.ts like :

```
import '../assets/xxxPath/xxx';
```

then added the following to CopyWebpackPlugin in

> webpack.common.js

like this

```
{ from: './src/main/webapp/assets/xxxPath', to: 'assets/xxxPath/'}
```

It works fine, but it makes huge main bundle js (5mb)! and performance problems.

Is there any fault in the procedure or do any suggestions to solve this issue and make a smaller bundle?

Comment: What’s in your file? Woulld it help to split it up in 2 parts: code and data? Data could be easily loaded on demand

Comment: I could spliting the my xxx.js by add to the entry point of webpack-dev/prod. Now I have diiferent chunk from main and remove import from vendor.ts. So, problem here is how can I tell to the webpack inject my xxx.js chunk in my component.html other than index.html. It seems jhipster use HtmlWebpackPlugin to inject chunks to index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

1- it is not necessary to copy js files to the directory. It causes huge bundle value and web performance problems. (So I removed `{ from: './src/main/webapp/assets/xxxPath', to: 'assets/xxxPath/'}` from webpack commom)

2- Instead of import in vendor.ts just simply import js lib into component ts and webpack will create a chunk for it and lazily loading by calling the module.